# COUNTIF returns 0 when expected 1

Tags: excel, google-sheets

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A28:AJ28,"*"&automation&"*")
, "need", "no need")
```

i expect this formula to return `'need'`
 but i get `'no need'`.

how should I change it?

[image]

Comment: Try `=IF(COUNTIF(A28:AJ28,"*automation*"), "need", "no need")`

Comment: Please. explain what you're trying to do (not just how), with some exact sample input data. It's not clear at all what you're trying to do, why, where `A28:AJ28` is, or what it contains.

Answer (score 3):

You've made your formula unnecessarily complex.

Because `automation` is outside the string it's not treated as a literal string, and inside the `COUNTIF` function you're getting a `#NAME!` error, which the `IF` function regards as false.

The following does work:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A28:AJ28,"*automation*"), "need", "no need")
```

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulate the text in double quotes:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A28:AJ28,"*" & "automation" & "*"), "need", "no need")
```